# How can I upgrade gnome shell to version 3.38 from 3.36 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and it currently runs gnome 3.36. I heard that gnome 3.38 has been released. I have tried everything that I could find on the internet but nothing has worked so far. The software updater does not show any update on gnome either. Please tell me what to do?

Comment: If you are a newbie user in any Linux distribution, the best advice would be: Wait until 20.10 is released (one month or so).

Comment: Thank you. Waiting is better than running into a bigger problem.